# Programmatically allow a non-author to edit a post based custom meta field

Tags: user-roles, author, editor, permissions

User A authored and published a post. In that post, User A selected User B as the "Manager" (a custom meta field).

How can I allow User B to edit any post in which they are selected as the "Manager"?

I'm comfortable with code. Looking for a way to programmatically hook into the check for who can edit a post.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [`current_user_can()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/)'s documentation, I see that it uses [WP_User::has_cap()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_User/has_cap/). So if your code (or the WP core code) uses something like `current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID )` to determine if the current user can edit the current post, you can use the [`user_has_cap`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_has_cap/) filter (called in `WP_User::has_cap()`):

```
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'wpse360937_allow_manager', 10, 4 );
function wpse360937_allow_manager( $allcaps, $caps, $args, $user ) {
    // Bail out if we're not asking about a post:
    if ( 'edit_post' != $args[0] ) {
        return $allcaps;
    }
    // Bail out for users who can already edit others posts:
    if ( $allcaps['edit_others_posts'] ) {
        return $allcaps;
    }
    // Bail out if the user is the post author:
    if ( $args[1] == $post->post_author ) {
        return $allcaps;
    }
    $post_id = $args[2]; 
    $manager_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'manager', true );
    // Assumes the meta field is called "manager" 
    // and contains the User ID of the manager.
    if ( $manager_id == $user->ID ) {
        $allcaps[ $caps[0] ] = true;
    }
    return $allcaps;
}
```

(Code partly based on the [User Contributed Notes on the `user_has_cap` filter docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_has_cap/#user-contributed-notes).)

Comment: Revisiting this because this solution has stopped working for me (actually, I'm doubting now if it ever worked). If anyone sees this and has insight, let me know.  The solution in this answer do allow the user to access a post's Edit screen, but upon clicking "Update" the site gives "Sorry, you are not allowed to edit posts as this user." I'm curious if this is the issue: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/post.php#L75

Comment: Took me a while to track down a fully working solution... here's where we landed: https://gist.github.com/brandonjp/bf8a2ef3cab014b5ae3dba3e510bca2d